# How to convert JTable column widths to a cell width in java iText pdf

Tags: java, swing, pdf, jtable, itext

I am working on an application where I have to map table cells one to one on the pdf.
For this purpose

I found Table cell widths

0:61
1:61
2:272
3:55
4:59

But on Pdf it looks different. Following is the sample code to demonstrate the problem:-

### SimpleTableDemo.java

```
package com.swing.data;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

import com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class SimpleTableDemo extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private boolean DEBUG = false;
    private static JTable table = null;
    private TableColumnAdjuster app = null;
    String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
            "Last Name",
            "Sport",
            "# of Years",
            "Vegetarian"};
    Object[][] data = {
            {"Kathy", "Smith",
             "SnowboardingXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
            {"John", "Doe",
             "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
            {"Sue", "Black",
             "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
            {"Jane", "White",
             "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
            {"Joe", "Brown",
             "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
            };
    CutomTableCellRenderer renderer = null;
    ArrayList<Integer> listColWidths = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public SimpleTableDemo() {
        super(new GridLayout(1,0));
        table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        renderer = new CutomTableCellRenderer(table.getDefaultRenderer(Object.class));
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, renderer);
        //table.setSelectionMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_SUBSEQUENT_COLUMNS);

        app = new TableColumnAdjuster(table);
        app.adjustColumns();
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        for(int i=0;i<table.getColumnCount();i++)
        {
            TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
            listColWidths.add(column.getWidth());
        }


        //Add the scroll pane to this panel.
        add(scrollPane);
        JButton button = new JButton("Print");
        add(button);
        button.addActionListener(this);
    }


    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleTableDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        SimpleTableDemo newContentPane = new SimpleTableDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        printPdf();

    }

    public void printPdf()
    {
        Document document = new Document();
        try {
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream("F://SimplePDFTable.pdf"));
            document.open();
            PdfPTable pdfTable = new PdfPTable(5);
            int tableWidths[] = new int[columnNames.length];
            for(int i= 0; i<listColWidths.size();i++)
            {
                tableWidths[i] = listColWidths.get(i);
            }
            pdfTable.setWidths(tableWidths);
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
            Phrase phrase = null;
            cell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
            cell.setBorderWidthLeft(1);
            for(int i=0;i<table.getColumnCount();i++)
            {
                phrase = new Phrase(columnNames[i]); 
                cell = new PdfPCell(phrase);
                pdfTable.addCell(cell);
            }
            for(int i=0;i<5;++i)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<5;++j)
                {
                    phrase = new Phrase(String.valueOf(data[i][j]));
                    cell = new PdfPCell(phrase);
                    pdfTable.addCell(cell);
                }
            }
            document.add(pdfTable);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        document.close();
    }
}
```

### TableColumnAdjuster.java

```
package com.swing.data;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

/*
 *  Class to manage the widths of colunmns in a table.
 *
 *  Various properties control how the width of the column is calculated.
 *  Another property controls whether column width calculation should be dynamic.
 *  Finally, various Actions will be added to the table to allow the user
 *  to customize the functionality.
 *
 *  This class was designed to be used with tables that use an auto resize mode
 *  of AUTO_RESIZE_OFF. With all other modes you are constrained as the width
 *  of the columns must fit inside the table. So if you increase one column, one
 *  or more of the other columns must decrease. Because of this the resize mode
 *  of RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS will work the best.
 */
public class TableColumnAdjuster implements PropertyChangeListener, TableModelListener
{
    private JTable table;
    private int spacing;
    private boolean isColumnHeaderIncluded;
    private boolean isColumnDataIncluded;
    private boolean isOnlyAdjustLarger;
    private boolean isDynamicAdjustment;
    private Map<TableColumn, Integer> columnSizes = new HashMap<TableColumn, Integer>();

    /*
     *  Specify the table and use default spacing
     */
    public TableColumnAdjuster(JTable table)
    {
        this(table, 6);
    }

    /*
     *  Specify the table and spacing
     */
    public TableColumnAdjuster(JTable table, int spacing)
    {
        this.table = table;
        this.spacing = spacing;
        setColumnHeaderIncluded( true );
        setColumnDataIncluded( true );
        setOnlyAdjustLarger( true );
        setDynamicAdjustment( false );
        installActions();
    }

    /*
     *  Adjust the widths of all the columns in the table
     */
    public void adjustColumns()
    {
        TableColumnModel tcm = table.getColumnModel();

        for (int i = 0; i < tcm.getColumnCount(); i++)
        {
            adjustColumn(i);
        }
    }

    /*
     *  Adjust the width of the specified column in the table
     */
    public void adjustColumn(final int column)
    {
        TableColumn tableColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column);

        if (! tableColumn.getResizable()) return;

        int columnHeaderWidth = getColumnHeaderWidth( column );
        int columnDataWidth   = getColumnDataWidth( column );
        int preferredWidth    = Math.max(columnHeaderWidth, columnDataWidth);
        System.out.println(column + ":" + preferredWidth);
        updateTableColumn(column, preferredWidth);
    }

    /*
     *  Calculated the width based on the column name
     */
    private int getColumnHeaderWidth(int column)
    {
        if (! isColumnHeaderIncluded) return 0;

        TableColumn tableColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column);
        Object value = tableColumn.getHeaderValue();
        TableCellRenderer renderer = tableColumn.getHeaderRenderer();

        if (renderer == null)
        {
            renderer = table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
        }

        Component c = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, false, false, -1, column);
        return c.getPreferredSize().width;
    }

    /*
     *  Calculate the width based on the widest cell renderer for the
     *  given column.
     */
    private int getColumnDataWidth(int column)
    {
        if (! isColumnDataIncluded) return 0;

        int preferredWidth = 0;
        int maxWidth = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).getMaxWidth();

        for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++)
        {
            preferredWidth = Math.max(preferredWidth, getCellDataWidth(row, column));

            //  We've exceeded the maximum width, no need to check other rows

            if (preferredWidth >= maxWidth)
                break;
        }

        return preferredWidth;
    }

    /*
     *  Get the preferred width for the specified cell
     */
    private int getCellDataWidth(int row, int column)
    {
        //  Inovke the renderer for the cell to calculate the preferred width

        TableCellRenderer cellRenderer = table.getCellRenderer(row, column);
        Component c = table.prepareRenderer(cellRenderer, row, column);
        int width = c.getPreferredSize().width + table.getIntercellSpacing().width;

        return width;
    }

    /*
     *  Update the TableColumn with the newly calculated width
     */
    private void updateTableColumn(int column, int width)
    {
        final TableColumn tableColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column);

        if (! tableColumn.getResizable()) return;

        width += spacing;

        //  Don't shrink the column width

        if (isOnlyAdjustLarger)
        {
            width = Math.max(width, tableColumn.getPreferredWidth());
        }

        columnSizes.put(tableColumn, new Integer(tableColumn.getWidth()));
        table.getTableHeader().setResizingColumn(tableColumn);
        tableColumn.setWidth(width);
    }

    /*
     *  Restore the widths of the columns in the table to its previous width
     */
    public void restoreColumns()
    {
        TableColumnModel tcm = table.getColumnModel();

        for (int i = 0; i < tcm.getColumnCount(); i++)
        {
            restoreColumn(i);
        }
    }

    /*
     *  Restore the width of the specified column to its previous width
     */
    private void restoreColumn(int column)
    {
        TableColumn tableColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column);
        Integer width = columnSizes.get(tableColumn);

        if (width != null)
        {
            table.getTableHeader().setResizingColumn(tableColumn);
            tableColumn.setWidth( width.intValue() );
        }
    }

    /*
     *  Indicates whether to include the header in the width calculation
     */
    public void setColumnHeaderIncluded(boolean isColumnHeaderIncluded)
    {
        this.isColumnHeaderIncluded = isColumnHeaderIncluded;
    }

    /*
     *  Indicates whether to include the model data in the width calculation
     */
    public void setColumnDataIncluded(boolean isColumnDataIncluded)
    {
        this.isColumnDataIncluded = isColumnDataIncluded;
    }

    /*
     *  Indicates whether columns can only be increased in size
     */
    public void setOnlyAdjustLarger(boolean isOnlyAdjustLarger)
    {
        this.isOnlyAdjustLarger = isOnlyAdjustLarger;
    }

    /*
     *  Indicate whether changes to the model should cause the width to be
     *  dynamically recalculated.
     */
    public void setDynamicAdjustment(boolean isDynamicAdjustment)
    {
        //  May need to add or remove the TableModelListener when changed

        if (this.isDynamicAdjustment != isDynamicAdjustment)
        {
            if (isDynamicAdjustment)
            {
                table.addPropertyChangeListener( this );
                table.getModel().addTableModelListener( this );
            }
            else
            {
                table.removePropertyChangeListener( this );
                table.getModel().removeTableModelListener( this );
            }
        }

        this.isDynamicAdjustment = isDynamicAdjustment;
    }
//
//  Implement the PropertyChangeListener
//
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e)
    {
        //  When the TableModel changes we need to update the listeners
        //  and column widths

        if ("model".equals(e.getPropertyName()))
        {
            TableModel model = (TableModel)e.getOldValue();
            model.removeTableModelListener( this );

            model = (TableModel)e.getNewValue();
            model.addTableModelListener( this );
            adjustColumns();
        }
    }
//
//  Implement the TableModelListener
//
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e)
    {
        if (! isColumnDataIncluded) return;

        //  A cell has been updated

        if (e.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE)
        {
            int column = table.convertColumnIndexToView(e.getColumn());

            //  Only need to worry about an increase in width for this cell

            if (isOnlyAdjustLarger)
            {
                int row = e.getFirstRow();
                TableColumn tableColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column);

                if (tableColumn.getResizable())
                {
                    int width = getCellDataWidth(row, column);
                    updateTableColumn(column, width);
                }
            }

            //  Could be an increase of decrease so check all rows

            else
            {
                adjustColumn( column );
            }
        }

        //  The update affected more than one column so adjust all columns

        else
        {
            adjustColumns();
        }
    }

    /*
     *  Install Actions to give user control of certain functionality.
     */
    private void installActions()
    {
        installColumnAction(true,  true,  "adjustColumn",   "control ADD");
        installColumnAction(false, true,  "adjustColumns",  "control shift ADD");
        installColumnAction(true,  false, "restoreColumn",  "control SUBTRACT");
        installColumnAction(false, false, "restoreColumns", "control shift SUBTRACT");

        installToggleAction(true,  false, "toggleDynamic",  "control MULTIPLY");
        installToggleAction(false, true,  "toggleLarger",   "control DIVIDE");
    }

    /*
     *  Update the input and action maps with a new ColumnAction
     */
    private void installColumnAction(
        boolean isSelectedColumn, boolean isAdjust, String key, String keyStroke)
    {
        Action action = new ColumnAction(isSelectedColumn, isAdjust);
        KeyStroke ks = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke( keyStroke );
        table.getInputMap().put(ks, key);
        table.getActionMap().put(key, action);
    }

    /*
     *  Update the input and action maps with new ToggleAction
     */
    private void installToggleAction(
        boolean isToggleDynamic, boolean isToggleLarger, String key, String keyStroke)
    {
        Action action = new ToggleAction(isToggleDynamic, isToggleLarger);
        KeyStroke ks = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke( keyStroke );
        table.getInputMap().put(ks, key);
        table.getActionMap().put(key, action);
    }

    /*
     *  Action to adjust or restore the width of a single column or all columns
     */
    class ColumnAction extends AbstractAction
    {
        private boolean isSelectedColumn;
        private boolean isAdjust;

        public ColumnAction(boolean isSelectedColumn, boolean isAdjust)
        {
            this.isSelectedColumn = isSelectedColumn;
            this.isAdjust = isAdjust;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //  Handle selected column(s) width change actions

            if (isSelectedColumn)
            {
                int[] columns = table.getSelectedColumns();

                for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++)
                {
                    if (isAdjust)
                        adjustColumn(columns[i]);
                    else
                        restoreColumn(columns[i]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (isAdjust)
                    adjustColumns();
                else
                    restoreColumns();
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     *  Toggle properties of the TableColumnAdjuster so the user can
     *  customize the functionality to their preferences
     */
    class ToggleAction extends AbstractAction
    {
        private boolean isToggleDynamic;
        private boolean isToggleLarger;

        public ToggleAction(boolean isToggleDynamic, boolean isToggleLarger)
        {
            this.isToggleDynamic = isToggleDynamic;
            this.isToggleLarger = isToggleLarger;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if (isToggleDynamic)
            {
                setDynamicAdjustment(! isDynamicAdjustment);
                return;
            }

            if (isToggleLarger)
            {
                setOnlyAdjustLarger(! isOnlyAdjustLarger);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From the above code when data is less it maps widths on the pdf correctly. But when column values are big and adjusted, the column widths calculated doesn't map to the correct pdfCell width.

Main highlights are:-

1. Data is filled inside a jtable
2. Table width is adjusted using TableColumnAdjuster
3. New column widths are stored inside a list
4. On print button these widths are used to print PdfCells on PdfPTable.

Please suggest something to map table cell width on the pdf.

[image]

Comment: `But on Pdf it looks different`. I don't have IText so I wan't run your code and I don't know what that statement means. Is every column a fixed size, is it off by one or two pixels. That information MIGHT help somebody make a guess. For example, probably won't make a difference, but as a general rule you should only get the columns widths at the time you are about to do the printing. So I would pass the table to the `printPDF()` method and get the columns widths there. That way you know for sure they haven't been modified from when the table was created until it was printed.

Comment: From the code it is evident that column widths are same. But data contents are wrapped on other line. Is that possible to show the contents one to one from JTable on the pdf Please suggest something on mapping @camickr

Comment: Again, I don't use IText, but I would guess that you need to configure it to use smaller margins. It looks to me like the table is being compress horzontally because the left/right margins are too wide.